# Convert Javascript array to PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

help! I am currently working on getting the content of  by class name using Javascript and store them into an array. Display array into drop-down list using php. This page is .php

What i have done so far:

Javascript:

```
var array = new Array();
$('.headline-bar').each(function () {
    array.push(this.innerHTML);
    array.serializeArray();
});
```

PHP :

```
<?php
$arrays = json_decode($_POST['array'], true);   
 foreach($arrays as $name) { ?>
      <option value="<?= $name['name'] ?>"><?= $name['name'] ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?>
```

Html:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">All</option>
      <?php
    $arrays = json_decode($_POST['array'], true);   
     foreach($arrays as $name) { ?>
          <option value="<?= $name['name'] ?>"><?= $name['name'] ?></option>
      <?php
        } ?>
    </select> 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

     <form action="#" id="release_year" method="post" > 
     <div class="headline-bar">2015</div> 
     <div class="headline-bar">2014</div>   
    </form>
```

Comment: The question is why? Why not pass the JS object to a Javascript function to populate the drop down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the [`serializeArray`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serializearray.asp) method but [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function to convert your array to a JSON string.

```
var array = new Array();
$('.headline-bar').each(function () {
    array.push(this.innerHTML);
});
var arrayJson = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Here the JSON string representing `array` is stored in `arrayJSON`.

Comment: Was just about to say this :P